# Getting "end of file" when passing complex type to WCF service

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I try to call a WCF service using jquery ajax POST with the following data:

> Data =
>   "{\"StudentID\":\"18\",\"Message\":{\"Header\":{\"EMailID\":\"0\",\"From\":{\"AddressType\":\"0\",\"AliasType\":\"0\",\"Name\":\"
>   Teacher\",\"StudentID\":\"18\",\"SymbolURL\":\"teacher.png\",\"Address\":\"18\"},\"To\":{\"AddressType\":\"0\",\"AliasType\":\"0\",\"Name\":\"Ian
>   \",\"StudentID\":\"346\",\"SymbolURL\":\"\",\"Address\":\"346\"},\"TimeRecieved\":\"/Date(0)/\"},\"version\":\"1\",\"MailMessageXML\":\"\",\"CompressedBody\":\"\"},\"ImageFileName\":\"\"}"

I get an error (response body):

> {"ExceptionDetail":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":null,"Message":"**Unexpected
>   end of file**.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ReadBOMEncoding(Boolean
>   notOutOfBand)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding
>   encoding)\u000d\u000a

......

This is my WCF function:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MailHeader
    {
        [DataMember] public Int64 EMailID;
        [DataMember] public MailAddress From;
        [DataMember] public MailAddress To;
        [DataMember] public DateTime TimeRecieved;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MailAddress
    {
        [DataMember] public Int64 AddressType;
        [DataMember] public Int64 AliasType;
        [DataMember] public string Name;
        [DataMember] public Int64 StudentID;
        [DataMember] public string SymbolURL;
        [DataMember] public string Address;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MailMessage
    {
        [DataMember] public MailHeader Header;
        [DataMember] public Int64 version;
        [DataMember] public XElement MailMessageXML;
        [DataMember] public byte[] CompressedBody;
    }

SendMessageStatusType SendMessage(Int64 StudentID, MailMessage Message,string ImageFileName);

This is my servicemodel from web.config:   
<system.serviceModel/>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataGetBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" ></serviceDebug>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="binaryEncoding" >
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


    <services>
      <service name="XXXX.Web.XXXXSVC" behaviorConfiguration="metadataGetBehavior">
        <endpoint address="ajax" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="XXXX.Web.IXXXXSVC" />
        <endpoint address="binary"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binaryEncoding"
          contract="XXXX.Web.IXXXXSVC" />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

The jquery call is simple and is the same as others which do work for me:

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST", 
    url: Url, // Location of the service
    data: Data, //Data sent to server
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processdata: false, //True or False
    success: function (msg) {

        //On Successfull service call

        successCallBackFunc(msg);

    },

    error: errorCallBackFunc  // When Service call fails

});
```

Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: I never did anything with WCF, neither I know its API, but are you sure you are expecting a JSON? There is an exception being thrown at some class called `System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper`...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out:

when you send an field of type: XElement, it cannot be an empty string and it must be in proper XML format.

same apply to type byte[], it must be at list: [0]